# Graph of non-linear variable on MatLab

Tags: matlab, math, nonlinear-functions

I'd like to get a **graph (e0, b)** from this non-linear function:

**C==(2*e0.*pi)/(log(b/a))**

I tried that code, but it did not work:

```
a = 1*10^-3; 
C=0.0001*10^-3;
e0=1:0.1*10^-3:7; 
fsolve(C==(2*e0.*pi)/(log(b/a)),b);
plot(e0,b)
```

How can I get this graph in MatLab?

Comment: The solution of this problem is kinda simple... the problem is that it will produce a scalar (actually `Inf`) because `e0=1:10^5:2;` doesn't produce a vector, but a scalar equal to `1`. `a` and `C` are scalars too.

Comment: The e0 is the range of the graph. I'm starting to use MatLab, I do not know how to fix the code to get the graph (e0, b).

Comment: Yeah well set a breakpoint and check what e0 looks like...

Comment: Got it. I changed e0 to 'e0=1:0.1*10^-3:7', now it's a vector, but when I run the code, it still shows that have an error.

Comment: This has no solutions for `b`. Anyway, declare `syms b;` at the top, replace `fsolve` with `solve` and mess around with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no graph to be had because `e0 = Inf`. The reason for this is if you rearrange your equation, you have:

```
b = a*exp(2*pi*e0/C);
```

with `e0` between `1` and `7` and `C` being `1e-7`, your values of be will be (ignoring `a`) between `exp(2*pi*1e7)` and `exp(14*pi*1e7)`. And guess what?

```
>> exp(2*pi*1e7)
ans = Inf
```

So either your values are wrong, your equation is wrong or there is no solution.